# What is "logger" in Java?

Tags: java, oop, methods, logging

I have a class in which I see the following things:

```
this.logger.severe("");
this.logger.warning("");
this.logger.info("");
```

I do not understand several things:

1. How can we use a method that was not defined earlier? I mean, there are no "logger" methods defined in the class. I thought that these methods could be defined because the considered class is an extension of another class in which the "logger" is defined. But in the definition of the class there no "extends" statement (only "implements").
2. I can understand things like that: "objectName.methodName". But what is that "objectName.something1.something2"? "something1.something2" is name of a method? Can method names contain dots?
3. What exactly these "logger.*" do? I think they save information about the execution of the code. They kind of write report about what happened during the execution. But where I can find this information?

**ADDED:**

In the beginning of the file I have: `import java.util.logging.Logger;`
And then in the class I have: `private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("a.b.c.d")`;
So, logger is an object of the class Logger (but I do not understand why they could not instantiate the class in a usual way using "new Logger()). I also do not understand what exactly logger.severe("") do.

Comment: To answer 2. method names cannot contain dots. Dot always means "the thing on the left is an object with members, and the thing on the right is the member I want to access". So if this code compiles, `logger` is a reference to an object with methods called `severe`, etc.

Comment: @divo: static fields are not accessible by `this`.

Comment: @BalusC, buy the way I do not understand why they use "this". I mean, if I use just field name, will it not be, by default, the field of this object? I there any difference between "this.x" and "x"?

Answer (score 13):

The logger doesn't make anything special. It's all just Java code.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Logger logger = LogFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);

    public void doSomething() {
        this.logger.debug("foo");
    }
}
```

The `this.logger` just points to the instance variable named `logger` of the current instance (`this`). The `this.` prefix is by the way superflous in this example. One could also just do `logger.debug("foo")` here.

If it is not declared in the `SomeClass` itself, then it's likely been declared in the extending class. Check the class which is declared in `extends`.

As to your `objectName.something1.something2` doubt, have you already looked how `System.out.println()` works? The [`System.out`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) returns a `PrintStream` object which in turn has a [`println()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) method. Thus, if `objectName.something` returns a fullworthy `Object` with methods, then you can just continue chaining method calls.

Basically,

```
objectName.something1.something2;
```

can be translated as

```
SomeObject someObject = objectName.something1;
someObject.something2;
```

But if you don't need `someObject` anywhere else in the code, then it can just be shortened as in your example.

**Update**: as per your update:

> So, logger is an object of the class Logger (but I do not understand why they could not instantiate the class in a usual way using "new Logger()). I also do not understand what exactly logger.severe("") do.

[Just read the javadoc of the class in question what it all does](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html). As to why it can't be instantiated, it's because of the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).

**Update 2**: as per the another confusion:

> I do not understand why they use "this". I mean, if I use just field name, will it not be, by default, the field of this object? I there any difference between "this.x" and "x"?

This way you can be more explicit about which one you'd like to access. If the method contains for example an argument or a local variable with the name `logger`, then `this.logger` would still refer to the instance variable.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Logger logger = LogFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);

    public void doSomething(Logger logger) {
        this.logger.debug("foo"); // Refers to the instance variable.
        logger.debug("foo"); // Refers to the method argument.
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        Logger logger = LogFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
        this.logger.debug("foo"); // Refers to the instance variable.
        logger.debug("foo"); // Refers to the method local variable.
    }
}
```

Comment: So, it is like that? If I see something like "aaa.bbb.ccc()" I can say that ccc() is a method of "aaa.bbb" and, as a consequence, "aaa.bbb" is an object. So, in the class "aaa" I should not search for the method called "bbb". Instead, I need to search for a field "bbb" defined in the class "aaa".

Comment: Good Detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

1. The 'logger' will be another object, not a method. This logger class will have methods defined on it like `public void severe(String message)`
2. 'something1' will be an object contained by 'objectName'. For example, `Car.Engine.Cylinder.Fire()`, it's considered bad practise to use a method to fire a car's cylinders like this, and you should do something more like `Car.StartEngine()` (see [the law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) for more info)
3. The logger will keep a record of what's happened in your program, so if there's a crash or a bug later on, you can see what happened. Whether this is recorded to a text file, or to a database somewhere, will be down to the implementation of your logger.

Answer (score 3):

1. The logger usually refers to the usage of a class in [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).
2. The logger is a member object whose function e.g. severe is called.
3. The logger usually logs into a file (this can be configured through log4j.xml or some other config file or during the program start).

**Edit:** Changed the log4j link.

Answer (score 1):

logger is not a method but a class variable which seems to be an object that exposes the methods "severe", "warning" and "info".

Check your class for something like "someClass logger = new someClass();"

Answer (score 1):

The java.util.Logger class is the main access point to the Java logging API. Here is how you create a logger:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
```

The string passed as parameter to the getLogger() factory method is the name of the Logger to create. You can choose the name freely, but the name implies where the Logger is located in the Logger hierarchy. Every . (dot) in the name is interpreted as a branch in the hierarchy.